# Импортирование в Python файлов с расширением, отличным от ".py"

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт

Как можно импортировать в Python 3.9.0 файл, с расширением отличным от ".py"? И стоит ли вообще это делать?

Имеется файл "main.py" и файл "config.cfg" с набором переменных и констант. Каким образом правильнее всего импортировать его в "main.py"?

Comment: Всм бл каким, чел, просто на будущее: расширения .py, .txt, .ini и тд- нужны только для индексации их программой, не больше. В каждом расширение хранится текст, не больше

Comment: Выходит, что можно прочитать хоть .png формат, обычным способом, как это принято делать в python

Comment: Правильнее всего — переименовать config.cfg в config.py и не заниматься самодеятельностью

Comment: покажите свой `config.cfg`

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer но при использовании "import config" выдаётся ошибка "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'.

Comment: @S.Nick  там только переменные типа:
PathDir = ' '
BuildNumber =  ''
key = ' '

Comment: На английском SO вроде есть [варианты решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601047/import-a-python-module-without-the-py-extension).

Comment: никаким образом, это не `.py` модуль, его можно просто открыть, либо спарсить конфиги, с помощью библиотек, например, `cfg-load`